# Trying to get Internet working on a new W11 VM installed with QEMU and Virtio

Tags: windows, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I'm a slightly more experienced Linux noobie  :-)
So I have

1. a new Ubuntu 22.04 server I installed XFCE4 and the ubuntu desktop
2. Installed QEMU/KVM virtmanager
3. Installed Win11 with virtio drivers using [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RiUrsljD_E)

All finally installed fine and network does get assigned an address, but there is no Internet!

Some information that may help
QEMU Virtual Network details

```
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>685fea15-5b93-45b1-b89d-c20d63d5185e</uuid>
  <forward mode="nat">
    <nat>
      <port start="1024" end="65535"/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name="virbr0" stp="on" delay="0"/>
  <mac address="52:54:00:51:ce:e2"/>
  <ip address="192.168.122.1" netmask="255.255.255.0">
    <dhcp>
      <range start="192.168.122.2" end="192.168.122.254"/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

I am connecting via Ethernet and this is my config

```
enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.50.6  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.50.255
        inet6 fe80::3a2c:4aff:fe64:61fe  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 38:2c:4a:64:61:fe  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 275414  bytes 281695923 (281.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 62844  bytes 9477221 (9.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:51:ce:e2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3492  bytes 199372 (199.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 493  bytes 58606 (58.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Anything else? please ask